# Getting access to array inside an object property

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I need to iterate through and it is built like this:

```
points[m] = {
   coordinate1: 34,
   coordinate2: 23,
   code: ["LEM"],
   location: '123 fake street'
}
```

If the current point(point[m]) matches another point I want to add the points[m].code to the point that it matched to build a unique array of objects like this:

```
pointsUnique[l].code.push(point[m].code[0]);
```

This works fine, except that when I try and iterate through (pointsUnique[l].code) like this:

```
 for(var n=0;n<pointsUnique[l].code.length;n++){
    var codeList = pointsUnique[l].code[n];
    console.log(codeList);
 }
```

I only get the 1 result in the code array because (pointsUnique[l].code.length) is apparently 1. Although it has 15 items in it when I view it in the console.

Any assistance on how I could access to all of the values of (pointsUnique[l].code) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think we'll need to see more of your code, ideally a **small**, self-contained, complete example demonstrating the problem. It's hard to infer your structures and such from what you've quoted. (If you're really pushing multiple items onto `pointsUnique[l].code`, then `pointsUnique[l].code.length` will be more than 1. So the question becomes: What's really happening, and how do we fix it.)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic looks good to me, so something else is probably going on. Are you copy/pasting your real code? For one, you've got a typo here:

`pointsUnique[l].code.push(point[m].code[0]);`

It should be `points[m]` not `point[m]`.

Also, what is this mysterious `l` variable? It could be a problem with that, too, though there's no way of knowing from the code you've posted.

Comment: These are *comments*, not an answer.

Comment: Well, the typo I pointed out would certainly fix the problem, assuming he pasted his code. It's impossible to know though because he hasn't given us much to work with, which I also pointed out. Downvote if you disagree.

Comment: I won't in this case. A downvote is for an answer that is "not useful." The ***comment*** that he has a typo *might* be useful. :-) But seriously, your clue that you're not *answering* a question is when you ask several questions instead.